# D&D 5e - Ready as Bonus Action [Custom Feat]

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, rogue, homebrew-review, archetype

I'm looking to make a custom feat in D&D. I'm building a hyper-mobility focused Rogue subclass that can teleport to an attuned object. I obviously don't want them to be able to teleport to it during someone else's turn, unless they use ready first. Thus, I was wondering if it would be reasonable to make a feat that lets you ready any non-attack action as a bonus action? Or would this feat be too weak on its own, or too strong?

Comment: Please see [How can I ask a good homebrew review question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question) – Balance is a tricky thing, and nearly impossible to answer without knowing what you got for your feat so far.

Comment: @Mołot this is not a [tag:hombrew-review] question. It is a question about [tag:hombrew]

Comment: @Akixkisu he is asking us to review balance of the feat he is homebrewing. That's in the question. Tags may be wrong or incomplete but it doesn't change what's asked.

Comment: @Mołot can you link me said feat? I haven't seen it yet. This is asking about what to consider when balancing such a feat - it is even feasible?

Comment: @Akixkisu Question is closed specifically because OP is talking about his homebrew feat he did not post. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it's too strong.  The action economy is a *huge* and critical part of how D&D 5e plays.  There's a ridiculous amount of shenanigans that this would enable.

Maybe make it really specific to that power -- at X level the Rogue gains the teleport ability; at Y level he can ready that teleport ability as a bonus action.  No feat, nothing anyone else gets to abuse, nothing the Rogue gets to abuse for any other purpose.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing! I will post a homebrew review in a little bit of the entire subclass with this exact idea in it, thank you so much!